# Cannot used CASE expression in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In the following query, `t2.stock` it has two values (`1` and `0`). I want the 1 value output as `IN` and `0` value as `OUT`. The problem is I can't use a `CASE` expression in this type of query. Is there any way to do this?

```
use DB1  
go

declare @SQL varchar(500),

Set @SQL=' select t1.ID,t1.Name,t2.stock 
    from table1 t1 
        inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID'

exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: Why can't you use a `CASE` statement?

Comment: Agreed with @Lamak. Please explain ***WHY*** you can't use `CASE`.

Answer (score 5):

If by *this type of query* you meant a dynamic query then you probably have some misconception about `CASE` and/or dynamic queries. Normally, there can be no problem using a `CASE` expression inside a dynamic query, an example of which can be seen in [@Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501739/297408).

However, if you absolutely insist, there *is* an alternative in your situation:

```
use DB1  
go

declare @SQL varchar(500);

Set @SQL=' select t1.ID, t1.Name, v.description as stock
    from table1 t1 
        inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
        inner join (
           values (1, ''IN''),
                  (0, ''OUT'')
        ) t2 (stock, description) on t2.stock = v.stock
';
exec (@SQL);
```

Answer (score 0):

But you *can* use a `case` statement in dynamic SQL:

```
use DB1  
go

declare @SQL varchar(500),

Set @SQL='
select t1.ID, t1.Name, (case when t2.stock = 1 then ''IN'' else ''OUT'' end) as stock
from table1 t1 
     inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
'

exec (@SQL)
```

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk . . . The statement is "The problem is I can't use "CASE' statement at this type of query."  I interpret that as the user doesn't know how to use a case statement in dynamic SQL.  If there is an environmental restriction or if this is a homework assignment, then the question should be clearer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree with your interpretation, but we need further clarification about that restriction, that's why I posted a comment there instead of just answer *use a `CASE`*